# Coupled 1-dimensional Allen-Cahn system

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose we solve Allen-Cahn on the interval $[-1,1]$

$$\epsilon^2 u_{xx} = u(u^2 - 1)$$
$$u(-1) = 0, \qquad u(1) = 0$$

For small $\epsilon$, such a solution is unique and can be chosen to be positive on the interior. Now suppose we also have a solution to the linearized equation with different boundary conditions

$$\epsilon^2\dot{u}_{xx} = (3 u^2 - 1) \dot{u}$$
$$\dot{u}(-1) = -1, \qquad \dot{u}(1) = 0$$

Can we find the sign of $\dot{u}_x(-1)$? i.e.

$$\text{sign}(\dot{u}_x(-1))$$